# This will be good. What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I start with an **A**

T**r**eachery is my territory

**G**oodwill does not include me

I am not **b**eloved by m**á**ny

**K**neel before **t**he God of Betrayal

As for I am a tr**u**e Portrayal

What am I?

***Tick tock children!***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a question (nice one me)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! 1: Riddles are usually not looked kindly upon here, since they're generally very low-quality. If you want to improve perception of your riddles, I strongly recommend learning about poetic metre and improving your rhymes. 2: Also, add some 'trick'. This isn't *really* a riddle: riddles need some form of wordplay or metaphor. This is just "object identification", which really isn't a puzzle. 3: This isn't steganography, since the message isn't hidden. The message is clear and easily spottable - steganographic messages should pass by unnoticed.

Comment: @Deusovi The steganography tag was my doing, since it was originally tagged cipher which was even further from the true nature of the puzzle.

Comment: I flagged this now again needing moderator attention, with the following explanation: "I flagged this as offensive, as playmate07 this is the very same guy, who posted a now-deleted 'puzzle' which was leading to a reddit page making fun of this site with offensive terms. My flag was declined, and I can understand it, as this post is not obviously as agressive as the previous was. Still, putting it in a larger context we cannot have realistic expectations about this question (or the user) improving our community. This is not just a poor question, but an offensive one."

Comment: @elias, I've responded to your flag. Check the response

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> [Argbáktu](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/Argb%C3%A1ktu:_Pagan_God_of_Treachery)? Because that's what the bold letters spell.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I _always_ spell many with an accent over the a.